# Relationship between kernel and board support package

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, bsp

In general, if I wanted to access(read or write) to some hardware device how do the kernel and bsp (board support package) interact to make this possible assuming the device drivers live inside the bsp?

Comment: BSP contains device drivers which are usually kernel modules. Kernel module could be loaded into kernel at runtime and became part of it. When modules are inserted, driver are registered which is usually a set of file operation for the device. These operation such as read/write/open/close/ioctl are the core logic.

Answer (score 0):

BSP comprises support for CPU/peripheral initialization and on-board peripheral specific functions, drivers. BSP shall have routines specific to entities like interrupt controller, rtc, timers, dma, uart/usb/ethernet/other-interfaces, spi/i2c, pci/isa bus, flash/ ROM/ EEPROM/ NVRAM, memory map, bootloader, filesystem etc. The routines shall be related to device selection/identification, registration, initialization/opening, reading/receiving, writing/sending or closing/freeing the device.

Normally, these routines shall be placed in respective processor directory/sub-directories. These functions shall be used/invoked by kernel in the form of device driver or independently as required by kernel. Since BSP is collection of hardware specific routines(or set of library), the BSP is also termed as a kind of interface between kernel/OS and on-board peripherals/hardware.